# Bootstrap Carousel with <a> element causes caption to disappear

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have this code,

```
<div class="item active">
  <a href="#" onclick="dynamicPlayer('http://example.com/video');return false;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#featuredVideoModal">
    <img src="http://example.com/img" alt="Once Place 2014 Promo" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 noPadding" />
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Test caption</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The `<a>` calls a function that sets the URL to be the video which JWPlayer will play inside of the modal that is called via the `data-target`. The problem is that the caption is not visible and I am not sure what CSS I need to change in order to make the caption text work. A codepen can be found here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qfwCn. Can anyone help?

Comment: try to move your caption outside of `<a>`

Comment: Just tried this and it did not make any difference. I inspected the caption area and it is center above the player instead of being over the image.

Comment: can you make a codepen or something like that?)

Comment: Have you tried removing the `return false;` ?

Comment: I tried removing the `return false;` and it did not make a difference. I also created a codepen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qfwCn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by removing `class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 noPadding"` from the `img`